# Centos 7 how get alternatives list for java

Tags: java, centos, centos7

I would like to get the list of all alternatives for java versions, choose one and set it in a script, but option --list doesn't work as expected:

```
alternatives --list java
alternatives version 1.7.4 - Copyright (C) 2001 Red Hat, Inc.
This may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU Public License.

usage: alternatives --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>
                    [--initscript <service>]
                    [--family <family>]
                    [--slave <link> <name> <path>]*
       alternatives --remove <name> <path>
       alternatives --auto <name>
       alternatives --config <name>
       alternatives --display <name>
       alternatives --set <name> <path>
       alternatives --list
common options: --verbose --test --help --usage --version --keep-missing
                --altdir <directory> --admindir <directory>
```

For the moment I create my own list with `/etc/alternatives`, but I'm not satisfied. How can I get a list like :

```
# alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
 + 1           java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
*  2           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
```

Comment: Umm ... am I missing something?  Can't you just get your script to run `alternatives --config java` if you want the user to choose, or `alternative --set java <path>`?

Comment: Anyhow, this shouldn't be tagged with `java` since it is entirely about wrangling the `alternatives` command.

Comment: I don't run run `alternatives --config java`, because it requires user input .You can use   `alternatives --set <name> <path>`

Comment: Correct.  So what is your question?

Comment: I don't want an user to choose which version, I want launch a script who require a specific version of openjdk, so I want to know if an alternative exits for this version. I need to get what usually you get with the command `alternatives --list java `, but for some reasons doesn't work here .

Comment: If you want your script to **use** a specific version of Java, you don't use "alternatives".  You simply add the path to the required version to the script's $PATH ... or use an absolute pathname.  And there are various symlinks to help you do this.

Comment: Sorry ... but alternatives is not smart enough to do this kind of thing.  You are better off just using your knowledge of how the *standard* openjdk symlinks work for your OS platform.

Comment: Ok, that's clearer, thank you; But do you have an idea why `alternatives --list `doesn't work?

Comment: Because it doesn't.  The `--list` option is designed to list all link groups and what they are currently configured to.  It don't take a `<name>` argument.  Like the `--help`  output and the manual entry both say.

Comment: But in the synopsis there is alternatives [options] --list name, this is what fooled me

Comment: True.  That's a documentation bug.

Comment: Ok, well thank you very much for your time given, I'hv learn a lot, it's a great day !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears than the option --list doesn't take arguments, it's a bug in the manual synopsis.Moreover for manage my java versions I should try env variables.

(The bug has been reported as https://github.com/fedora-sysv/chkconfig/issues/11)

Answer (score 1):

Use this command `alternatives --list` to get available versions on cli.

```
[root@88a15b43eab2 /]# alternatives --list
ld  auto    /usr/bin/ld.bfd
libnssckbi.so.x86_64    auto    /usr/lib64/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
jre_openjdk auto    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
java    auto    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java
jre_1.8.0_openjdk   auto    /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64
jre_1.8.0   auto    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
```